# Maximum cover with $k$ element

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

I want to solve the following problem :

For two set $\mathcal N$ and $\mathcal E$, we have a binary matrix $A$ index by $\mathcal N \times \mathcal E$ and we say that $e\in \mathcal E$ covers $n \in \mathcal N$ if $a_{n, e}= 1$. We are looking for the maximum set of $\mathcal N$ covered by exactly $k$ elements in $\mathcal E$.

I know that we can write this problem as an integer program. However, I want to have a combinatorial algorithm to solve it.
Can anyone help me to find good heuristic or an exact algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you are asking about so-called Maximum Coverage problem. It is so well known and investigated, that I can easily provide you a very brief survey on it, containing a list of its applications, results of its computational complexity and approximability, related problems and more easy special cases. Namely, this is the beginning of the introduction of the paper “[Approximation Schemes for Geometric Coverage Problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06665)” by Steven Chaplick, Minati De,  Joachim Spoerhase, and me. :-)